# Can we rename the [stormlight-archives] tag to [stormlight-archive]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

We have a [stormlight-archives](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stormlight-archives) tag, for the Brandon Sanderson's series, but the correct name of the series is Stormlight Archive (singular; without the `s` at the end).

Can we replace this tag with [stormlight-archive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stormlight-archive)? I am not allowed to do that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ninja @randal'thor again, hmm?

[status-completed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), by @rand al'thor. Now to fix the tag wikis!

Comment: Damn, you are quick :-) Tag wikis should all be fine this time.

Comment: @randal'thor Yup - i'm stalking the front page. I had submitted an edit to the tag wikis, but you got to them first :/

Comment: I put in the tag wikis for the new tag before the merge, and those for the old tag disappeared after the merge. Not sure when you submitted an edit, but I think it's all fine now.

Comment: @randal'thor Around 30 seconds after you made the switch.

Comment: Just noticed this.  Updated a few other wikis that linked the tag too.